# Name for tall zero-one matrix with unit row sum?

Tags: matrices

Is there a special name for tall zero-one matrix with unit row sum? Call the matrix C.

For a data matrix D, the product DC combines columns of D by purely summing without scaling. The rationale is to preserve a dirichlet distribution property that relates to combined data counts.

Binary feature selection matrix ? 
Possibly used in relation to clustering work. 
Or perhaps in specifying equivalence classes. 
Or perhaps there is no special name for this kind of matrix.

Thank you for your thoughts on this.

Comment: A "zero-one matrix with unit row sum?" So there is a single one per row? I'd call it a selection matrix since it just selects a single element of the vector it multiplies.

Comment: Data is on the left and C may have multiple ones per column. So the action of a column of C is to select a handful of columns of D and add them. My hesitation to call it 'selection' is that it suggests the chosen columns are distinctly preserved, when in fact they are combined in a lossy way.